# What is the dependent formula of the vectors

Tags: linear-algebra

Are vectors $(1,0,3,4)$, $(1,0,1,1)$, $(4,1,2,3)$ and $(6, 1,8,11)$ linearly
dependent? If yes, what is  the dependence formula.

I found out the determinant is $0$ isn't is supposed to be independent and what is dependance formula. 
What is the dependance formula in this case?

Comment: If you know the determinant is $0$, what can you conclude about the dependence/independence of these vectors? Hint: consult your notes or textbook and consider that I am writing another sentence. For the second part, do you know how to reduce a matrix?

Comment: I dont have text book but I see in web that it is dependant

Comment: and yes i know how to reduce a matrix but the problem is I am getting 0 in the last row so i will not x4 and what is dependence formula

Comment: It is normal to get all zeros in the last row for a set of dependent vectors. What do you get in row 3?

Comment: i get 0 0 1 1 but is this dependent or independetn

Comment: The vectors are dependent. The last row gives you one equation with two unknowns. That gives you the freedom to choose. If your four variables are $x$, $y$, $z$ and $w$ this equation says $z+w=0$ so $z=-w$. You are free to choose $w$ so make it equal to 1. Now you have $z=-1$. Work your way up the matrix solving for $x$ and $y$. When you are finished you will have the coefficients needed to write down the dependent equation.

Comment: how would i get z=-1

Comment: o get x=-w. y=0, z=-w what will do from here

Comment: Set $w=1$ and plug in. Are you sure about $x$? I got $-2w$. After you get those numbers you check that $x(1.0,3,4) + y(1,0,1,1) + z(4,1,2,3) + w(6,1,8,11)=0$. That's your dependence equation.

Comment: My bad yes it is 2

Comment: y=0 so do i need to write 2 nd part

Comment: It shouldn't matter. If you know that three vectors are linearly dependent then that doesn't change by adding more vectors.

Answer (score 1):

We have, $$(6,1,8,11)=2(1,0,3,4)+0(1,0,1,1)+(4,1,2,3).$$

So if the vectors are dependent, then we must can write one of them as $(6,1,8,11)$ as linear combination of others:

$$c_1(1,0,3,4)+c_2(1,0,1,1)+c_3(4,1,2,3)=(6,1,8,11)$$

By solving this system, we will have $$c_1=2,c_2=0,c_3=1.$$

Answer (score 0):

You can either calculate the determinant, or you can put you vectors as rows in matrix $A$ and try to find the row reduced echelon form.

If the row reduced echelon form leaves one row with only zeros, what does this mean?

What you are doing when you find the row reduced echelon form, is actually to try to eliminate entries in your matrix by writing the rows as linear combination of each other. And a set of vectors are linearly independent if you cant write one vector of them as a linear combination of the other vectors, of more formal:

let $v_1, v_2 \cdots v_n$ be a set of vectors. Then they are linearly independent if
$$ \alpha_1 v_1 + \alpha_2 v_2 + \cdots + \alpha_n v_n = 0 $$ implies
$$ \alpha_1 = \alpha_2 = \cdots \alpha_n = 0. $$

Remember that if the determinant of the row reduced echelon form is zero then also the determinant of the original matrix is zero.

Comment: i found from  rref that x1+x4= 0   x2=0  x3+x4 =0

Comment: Wolfram Alpha sais: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=rref%7B%7B1%2C0%2C3%2C4%7D%2C%7B1%2C0%2C1%2C1%7D%2C%7B4%2C1%2C2%2C3%7D%2C%7B6%2C1%2C8%2C11%7D%7D